# Clicking on choosen coordinates in WebGL (canvas)

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, capybara, unity-webgl

I am working with an app which embeds a WebGL Player.

```
<body>
  <div class="application_layout">
    <header class="header clearfix">
      <nav class="header__left">
        <ul class="clearfix">
          <li class="menu__item menu__item--back">
            <a title="Back" class="link--back"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="unity-webgl">
      <canvas style="cursor: default;" id="#canvas" width="1596" height="386"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

In my acceptance tests with `RSpec` and `capybara` I'm trying to simulate the click action on the page.

When doing

```
execute_script("$(document.elementFromPoint(100, 20).click();")
# the position of the "Back" link
```

everything is obviously working fine and the script is correctly clicking on the "Back" link.

But when trying to click on any area of the WebGL div with something like

```
var event = $.Event('click');
event.clientX = 200;
event.clientY = 100;
$('#canvas).trigger(event);
```

nothing is happening.

Is there any way to simulate the mouse click on the WebGL div?

Comment: may you add the **Back** link ...... (create a snippet)? Thanks

Comment: I'ts already in the code @gaetanoM . 7th line.

Comment: because the id of your canvas is id="#canvas" you need to escape the first char in jQuery selector:  $('#\\#canvas').  Does this solve your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be trying to simulate clicks - you should just tell Capybara to do the click.  If you need the click to be offset use the options available to the click method.

```
element.click(x: 200, y: 100)
```

Any time you resort to using JS to fire events on the page you're making your tests less useful/valid since it allows for doing things a user never could.

Comment: Hey Thomas, would you propose something else? Actually this is something a user would do, but since it's not possible to interact without JS with a WebGL frame, I thought it was the best workaround.

Comment: @fabersky Are you sure it's not possible - have you tried just using the Capybara provided `click` with an x,y offset as shown in my answer?

Comment: @fabersky Also to click the back link you should just be doing `click_link('Back')` not executing a click via JS

Comment: Yes, the `execute_script("$(document.elementFromPoint(100, 20).click();")` was just to check that the script was working for non-WebGl content.

Comment: @fabersky So did you try just finding the canvas element, and calling click on it (with an offset) from ruby instead of using `execute_script`

Comment: Thomas, what should `element` be in this case? `('#canvas')`?

Comment: @fabersky If that's the element you need to offset the click from then yes - `find(:id, '#canvas').click(x:  x_offset, y: y_offset)` , or maybe you want to offset from the wrapping div `find('#unity-webgl').click(x: x_offset, y: y_offset)`

Comment: Not working... the elements are found but any click is performed.

Comment: @fabersky https://gist.github.com/twalpole/dcfebfa9021a35a9643bf9e122b10184 - That's a gist showing the canvas element does receive the click -- so I'm not really sure what you're doing differently.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the `rumouse` gem. But it doesn't work with headless, it requires the window focus and the coordinates are system-wide.